# Socket IO not properly closing connection

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm `tail`ing a log file and stream the new lines to a websocket.

Since I have multiple logs, I let the user choose the log file and then get the details of that log.

The problem is that when I close a connection in order to see a different log, the connection does something weird, that when I start it again, it streams the data twice. If I close the connection and re-open it again, it streams 3 times the data, so on and so forth.

My `package.json`:

```
{
    "socket.io": "^2.0.3",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.3"
}
```

**Client side**

```
$("#detailsBtn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get('/get/details', {
        // some-data
    }, () => {
        if (socket) socket.close();
        socket = io('http://localhost:4000', {forceNew: true});
        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('connected');
        });
        socket.on('newLine', function (msg) {
            // do-stuff
        });
    });
});
$('#closeBtn').click(function () {
    socket.disconnect();
    socket.close();
});
```

**Server side**

```
app.get('/details', (req, res) => {
    const tail = spawn('ssh', ['root@' + req.query.srv, req.query.script]);
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log(`connect ${socket.id}`);
        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log(`DISconnected ${socket.id}`);
        });
        tail.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            socket.emit('newLine', {message: data});
        });
    });
    return res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Now when simulating the button click, I expect the socket and connection to be closed, in order to make a new one.

**Server console log** (each time I click the button only once)

```
Server listening on localhost:4000

**click on detailsBtn**
GET /get/details?srv=myserver.google.com&script=%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Ftail 304 16.003 ms - -
connect YyYHFI9CARpBHaxoAAAB
**click on closeBtn**
DISconnected YyYHFI9CARpBHaxoAAAB

**click on detailsBtn**
GET /get/details?srv=myserver.google.com&script=%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Ftail 304 6.308 ms - -
connect vzfBnUPHUqYXd5qaAAAC
connect vzfBnUPHUqYXd5qaAAAC
**click on closeBtn**
DISconnected vzfBnUPHUqYXd5qaAAAC
DISconnected vzfBnUPHUqYXd5qaAAAC

**click on detailsBtn**
GET /get/details?srv=myserver.google.com&script=%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Ftail 304 4.677 ms - -
connect 3quEe5G1gFDJ2BvrAAAD
connect 3quEe5G1gFDJ2BvrAAAD
connect 3quEe5G1gFDJ2BvrAAAD
**click on closeBtn**
DISconnected 3quEe5G1gFDJ2BvrAAAD
DISconnected 3quEe5G1gFDJ2BvrAAAD
DISconnected 3quEe5G1gFDJ2BvrAAAD
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Symptoms like this are usually caused by duplicate event handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the comments here directed me to the solution.

I had duplicate event handlers for both the `socket` and the `tail`.

I called the initiation of the connection each time a user clicked the button, and I `spawn`ed a `tail` child process each time the URL was accessed
Here is how I fixed it:

**Socket**

1.Moved the `io.on('connection'...)` outside of the `app.get` handler as suggested by @alex-rokabilis

2.Created an event emmiter of my own:

```
const events = require('events');
const eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
```

3.Inside `io.on('connection'...)`, instead of listening to `tail.stdout` event, I listened to my `eventEmitter` event in order to be able to use the `tail` outside of the `app.get` handler

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    eventEmitter.on('newLine', (data) => {
        socket.emit('newLine', {line: data});
    });
});
```

4.In the `app.get` handler, I listen to `tail.stdout.on('data'...` and send an `eventEmitter` event that would be handled inside the `io` object:

```
app.get('/details', (req, res) => {
    let tail = spawn('ssh', ['root@' + req.query.srv, req.query.script]);
    tail.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        eventEmitter.emit('newLine', data.toString().replace(/\n/g, '<br />'));
    });
});
```

5.On client, I moved the `io` initialization outside of the ajax call, defined socket in a way I could use further in the script.

```
let socket = io('http://localhost:4000', {forceNew: true});
socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('connected');
});
socket.on('newLine', function (msg) {
    // do-stuff
});

$("#detailsBtn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get('/get/details', {
        // some-data
    });
});
```

**Tail**

This was a bit hard to find, I always thought the problem is with the socket-io rather than the `tail`.

Inside `io.on('connection'...`, I added a socket listener for an event named `closeConnection` that emits `closeConnection` to my `eventEmitter`, that in turn kills the `tail` child process:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    eventEmitter.on('newLine', (data) => {
        socket.emit('newLine', {line: data});
    });
    socket.on('closeConnection', () =>{
        console.log('got connection close from client');
        eventEmitter.emit('closeConnection');
    });
});
```

And inside the `app.get` controller:

```
app.get('/details', (req, res) => {
    let tail = spawn('ssh', ['root@' + req.query.srv, req.query.script]);
    tail.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        eventEmitter.emit('newLine', data.toString().replace(/\n/g, '<br />'));
    });
    eventEmitter.on('closeConnection', () => {
        tail.stdin.pause();
        tail.kill();
    });
});
```

And in the client, each time I want to close the connection, I just:

```
socket.emit('closeConnection');
```

That was tough.

Answer (score 1):

As you see in the console logs, the connect and disconnect shows the same socketID. This indicates that the event handler is triggered many times.
From your code you define a new event handler for `'connection'` every time the `'/details'` route is getting a request.
So a better aproach would be...

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(`connect ${socket.id}`);
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(`DISconnected ${socket.id}`);
    });
    tail.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        socket.emit('newLine', {message: data});
    });
});
app.get('/details', (req, res) => {
   const tail = spawn('ssh', ['root@' + req.query.srv, req.query.script]);
   return res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: It throws error: `tail is not defined`. I also tried moving the whole `tail.stdout` part to the `app.get` and then `socket is not defined`.